# JSON Type not supported for int datatype --> JSON type not supported. (Parameter 'ValueKind')\r\nActual value was Number

Tags: c#, jsonelement

I have a class `Person` that has an `Age` property which is an `int`. It is persisted down to Cosmos Graph DB. I use the GremlinClient to fetch the record and then I have a `Materialize` method to rebuild `<T>`. If the `Person` class doesn't have any `int` types it works fine, however my method fails somewhere.

Coming back from the Graph, my result looks good:

[image]

Few things to note about the above:

1. it is an `IDictionary<string, object>` and it has 4 entry.
2. the 4th entry actually holds the properties of the `Person` object as they exist in the `vertex` in the graph
   [image]
   Few things to note:
3. Although the resulting value in the dictionary entry (`object`) is a value "Bob", "Oak
   , 32, etc. it comes from the Gremlin client as `System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectEnumerableIterator<System.Text.Json.JsonElement, object>` which my method attempts to extract the value and then recreate `<T>` and return `T`.

Here's how I found it.[link](https://github.com/crosscutsolutions/gremlin.linq/blob/5ff88cce7779746a8ce865773074870fbd58ab8a/Gremlin.Linq/GremlinGraphClient.cs#L134) I have made some changes to this method but it still throws the same error, apparently its the `SelectEnumerableIterator` doesn't like `Int`s for some reason.

Hoping one of you can help me!

**Error and Stack Trace:**

```
    ActualValue: Number
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HResult: -2146233086
    HelpLink: null
    InnerException: null
    Message: "JSON type not supported. (Parameter 'ValueKind')\r\nActual value was Number."
    ParamName: "ValueKind"
    Source: "Gremlin.Net"
    StackTrace: "   at Gremlin.Net.Structure.IO.GraphSON.GraphSONReader.ToObject(JsonElement graphSon)
\r\n   at Gremlin.Net.Structure.IO.GraphSON.GraphSONReader.<ReadDictionary>b__6_1(JsonProperty property)
\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector)
\r\n   at Gremlin.Net.Structure.IO.GraphSON.GraphSONReader.ReadDictionary(JsonElement jsonDict)
\r\n   at Gremlin.Net.Structure.IO.GraphSON.GraphSONReader.ToObject(JsonElement graphSon)
\r\n   at Gremlin.Net.Structure.IO.GraphSON.GraphSONReader.<ToObject>b__4_0(JsonElement t)
\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectEnumerableIterator`2.ToList()"    TargetSite: {System.Object ToObject(System.Text.Json.JsonElement)}
```

Comment: Any updates on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There's a discussion on the same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68092798/gremlin-net-deserialize-number-property/72316108#72316108), and I've posted a work-around until Cosmos updates their support.

Comment: This worked for me